# Applications continue to use original audio device, even though I selected a different default audio device

Tags: windows-7, audio, switch, playback

Problem example:

- Default Audio Device is my Headset. ITunes playback through headset.
- I switch  Default Audio Device to Monitor. ITunes *continues* playback
  through headset.

This happens visa versa as well, so if the first audio device was the monitor. I have to restart the application for it to update the playback device.

This only occurs for certain applications like ITunes and League of Legends. However Chrome is not affected, so youtube videos transition fine from headset to monitor. And all new audio will work through the current default device. Just previously active audio is affected on certain applications.

This was never an issue. my setup used to work fine but at some point it stopped working so there must be a fix.

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

OS: Windows 7 SP1

**Update:**

***Fix:***
After messing around with many settings I discovered ITunes had an option for playback to be through either *Windows Audio Session* or *Direct Sound* under Edit - Preferences - Playback.

It was set to Windows Audio Session, I changed it to Direct Sound and now I can transition my playback devices seamlessly on ITunes. However does anyone know how to set this for all applications? i.e. Steam games/League of Legends?

Comment: you can also answer your own questions. it makes the answer more obvious for ppl who land here through google.

Answer (score 0):

In your sound device settings, open the properties for your headset uncheck "Allow programs to take control of this device" or "exclusive access", you'll know it when you see it.

Comment: This is already unchecked for all devices. Thanks though, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue, and found the same fix - switching from Windows Audio Session to Direct Sound was the solution. Now when I switch from speakers to headset or to a wireless speaker or vice-versa, I don't have to restart iTunes - the music continues without interruption.

Comment: The OP already tried that, so this really doesn't contribute any new content.